# HTML Email isn't being sent when form is submitted to the same PHP file

Tags: php, html, email

I was working on a message form that sends a copy of the message to the email address when it is submitted. It worked fine when the `form action` directed to a different php file. But when I directed the form to submit itself to the same file the form is in it sent the message to the database but didn't send the email. It would be great if someone could tell me why this is happening. Here's the code for `contact.php`file:

```
        <div class="form-wrap">
            <form class="form-flex" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <label for="">Send us a message</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="text" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <button class="btn-big" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $message = $_POST['message'];

                        $connection = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'messages');

                        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
                        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
                        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $message);

                        if($connection) {
                            $query = "INSERT INTO msg(name,email,message) ";
                            $query .= "VALUES ('$name','$email','$message')";

                            mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            $email_subject = 'New Message';
                            $email_body = $message;
                            $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
                            mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body);

                            echo "<p class='form'>Message sent!</p>";
                        } else {
                            die("<p class='form'>Database connection failed</p>");
                        }                   
                    } 
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: wrap `mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body)` in a try/catch block and see if you get an exception

Comment: If you get Db row inserted, then it means something wrong with `mail` function. I suggest using some lib like PHPMailer instead of `mail` function. Make sure you set proper headers for email to be successfully sent. Sometimes client may reject your simple `mail()` emails

Comment: Yash Karanke, the try/catch block didn't return any exception but still I'm not getting any email.

Comment: Justinas, I tried it using the headers also but it didn't work. And yeah I think the problem is the mail function. But why was it working when the form was being submitted to a different php file?

Comment: you're missing the **headers** for the mail function.

Comment: So here's a crazy thing that solved the issue. I changed ````email_subject```` from 'New Message' to 'New Form Submission' (which I changed before and somehow this was causing the problem) and now the email is being sent. I've never been more baffled by a bug.